# Tic Tac Toe Trouble ( some logical mistakes )

Tags: c++, if-statement, logical-operators

I am writing this tic tac toe program using classes. I wrote this function called `makeAMove()`. This function is supposed to validate the move of the player, but it keeps displaying that it's an invalid move and it's asking the player to reenter. There's probably a few logical errors, but I am just not seeing them. Can anyone help? It's a class that uses an object called `Cell board[ROW][COL]` and another object called `Player players[2]`. The markers are either `X` or `O`, while the `iVal` is the initial value of the board ( each cell on the board has a number from 1 - 9 ). Included in here is the `winGame()` and the `switchPlayer()` for your reference. While I think my `winGame()` function is ok, I know I can do this using sums. In other words, each cell has in internal marker like -1 or 1 and if the sum of the rows, columns, etc, is -3 or 3, the internal marker corresponding to the player will output a winner. If you have any insight on how to do this, feel free to share, otherwise, my `winGam`e is fine.

```
int TicTacToe::switchPlayer(){
        if ( currentPlayer == 0)
                currentPlayer = 1;
        else if ( currentPlayer == 1 )
                currentPlayer = 0;

        return (currentPlayer);
}
//
//method to make a move
//
void TicTacToe::makeAMove(){
        char move;
        int turns = 1;
        do{
                cout << "Player " << (getCurrentPlayer() + 1) << " make a move." << endl;
                cin >> move;
                for ( int i = 0; i < ROW; i++ ){
                        for ( int j = 0; j < COL; j++ ){
                                //This is where my problem begins
                                if ( board[i][j].getiVal() == move ){
                                        board[i][j].setiVal( players[currentPlayer].getMarker());
                                        DrawBoard();
                                        switchPlayer();
                                        turns++;
                                }

                                else if ( board[i][j].getiVal() == 'X' || board[i][j].getiVal() == 'O'){
                                        cout << "Invalid move, please reenter. " << endl;
                                        cin >> move;
                                }//the else if statement always outputs:x
                        }
                }
        } while ( turns <= 9 || !winGame() );
        cout << "Congratulations " << ( getCurrentPlayer() + 1 ) << "you won the game!" << endl;
}
bool TicTacToe::winGame(){
        bool validate = false;
        int k = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < ROW; i++ ){
                //check column wins
                if ( board[0][i].getMarker() == board[1][i].getMarker() && board[1][i].getMarker() == board[2][i].getMarker()){
                        players[currentPlayer].setNumWin(k++);
                        validate = true;
                        break;
                }
                //check row wins
                else if ( board[i][0].getMarker() == board[i][1].getMarker() && board[i][1].getMarker() == board[i][2].getMarker()){
                        players[currentPlayer].setNumWin(k++);
                        validate = true;
                        break;
                }
        }

        if( board[0][0].getMarker() == board[1][1].getMarker() && board[1][1].getMarker() == board[2][2].getMarker()){
                players[currentPlayer].setNumWin(k++);
                validate = true;
        }
        else if ( board[0][2].getMarker() == board[1][1].getMarker() && board[1][1].getMarker() == board[2][0].getMarker()){
                players[currentPlayer].setNumWin(k++);
                validate = true;
        }

        return (validate);
}
```

This is a sample run of the program

```
    +--+--+--+
    |1 |2 |3 |
    +--+--+--+
    |4 |5 |6 |
    +--+--+--+
    |7 |8 |9 |
    +--+--+--+
    Player 1 make a move.
    1

    +--+--+--+
    |O |2 |3 |
    +--+--+--+
    |4 |5 |6 |
    +--+--+--+
    |7 |8 |9 |
    +--+--+--+
    Player 2 make a move.
    5
    Invalid move, please reenter.
    6

    +--+--+--+
    |O |2 |3 |
    +--+--+--+
    |4 |5 |X |
    +--+--+--+
    |7 |8 |9 |
    +--+--+--+
    Player 1 make a move.
```

Answer (score 1):

The logical error here can be reduced to the following:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < ROW; i++ ){
   for ( int j = 0; j < COL; j++ ){
         if ( board[i][j].getiVal() == move ){

               // Not important what happens here
         }
   else if ( board[i][j].getiVal() == 'X' || board[i][j].getiVal() == 'O'){
               cout << "Invalid move, please reenter. " << endl;

               // Not important what happens here
   }
```

The logical error can be identified here using the "Rubber Duck" approach to debugging.

The "Rubber Duck" approach to debugging involves taking a rubber duck, the kind that floats in the bathtub, putting it down next to your monitor screen, then attempting to explain to the rubber duck what your code is doing, and you keep explaining until you figure out the problem yourself.

Here, you will begin by explaining to your rubber duck that your code is going to scan the tic-tac-toe matrix, a row at a time, and a column at a time, starting at the upper-left corner, and ending at the lower right corner. That's what the nested for-loops are doing here.

The rubber duck will agree, and you will continue to explain this code.

You will now tell your rubber duck that your code will keep scanning the tic-tac-toe board until it sees either a `move` or an `X` or an `O` at the current position it is scanning. If it sees the `X` or the `O`, your code is going to complain that the move is invalid.

Therefore, if the first cell, the cell in the top-left corner, contains an 'X' or an 'O' this code will see it on the first iteration in the inner loop, and report an error message, no matter what else is contained in the rest of the tic-tac-toe matrix.

At this point, you have successfully identified the logical error here, using the Rubber Duck approach to debugging.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I'm just slightly confused as to how to go about setting my X's and O's

Comment: If you understand what the logical problem is, then the solution should be obvious. Hint: if the next move is for cell #n, where n is 1 through 9, then the next move is for row (n-1)/3, column (n-1)%3. Try this math yourself, to verify this earth-shattering discovery (when n=6, for example, this comes to row (6-1)/3=1, column (6-1)%3=2), then try to figure out WHY the math works like that. The rest should be obvious. The nested for loops are not needed at all.